# how to implement Collection object

Tags: c#, .net, collections

how to implement collection objects of my class?

something like `MatchCollection` or `CookieCollection`

For example:

I have the following class:

```
public class theParserClass 
{
    public theParserClass(string baa)
    { 
      //..
    }

    public string pro1 
   {
     get { /* etc */ } 
   }
}
```

and the collection that I want to implement:

```
 public class theParserClassResultCollection
    {
       private ParserResultCollection result; 
       public theParserClassResultCollection(string[] baa)
       { 

         foreach(string foo in baa)
         {
           var data = new theParserClass(foo);
           result.Add(data);
         }
       }

       public ParserResultCollection() 
       {
        return result;            
       }

    }
```

I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with `System.Collections.Generic.List`? Your purpose here is not clear.

Comment: Just write a little helper method that takes a string[] and returns a, say, `List<Foo>` where Foo is the result of parsing a string.  Which wouldn't be theParserClass, that should just be an internal helper class that converts a string to a Foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the ObservableCollection like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ParserClass> GetCollection(string[] baa)
{
  var result = new ObservableCollection<ParserClass>();
  foreach(string foo in baa)
  {
    var data = new ParserClass(foo);
    result.Add(data);
  }
  return result;
}

public class ParserClass 
{
  public ParserClass (string baa)
  { 
    //..
  }

  public string pro1 
  {
    get { /* etc */ } 
  }
}
```

msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

hope this helps

Comment: It is not it... I need 'create' a type as MatchCollection that save n result of class x. I tried using List, but the type should be 'someCollection'

Comment: I still do not understand! You want something like that? public class ParserClassCollection : ObservableCollection<ParserClass> { ... } or something like that? public class ParserClassCollection : ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ParserClass>> { ... }

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are declaring what appears to be the constructor of `ParserResultCollection` inside the class `theParserResultCollection`. Don't really know what that is supposed to mean.

The general idea you can use is to make a wrapper class over an existing collection (inheritance by composition) and provide the methods that you need using the inner collection object. Like:

```
public class ParserResultCollection
{
    private List<ParserClass> collection;

    public ParserResultCollection(string[] param)
    {
        collection = new List<ParserClass>(param);            
    }

    public void Add(ParserClass item)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
    }

    // whatever else you need.
}
```

Of course, if you don't need any other special functionality with respect to the existing collections, just use them instead.

And drop the "the", just `ParserResultCollection`. It's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
  public class Collection<T> : IList<T>, 
        ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx